# FetchXML Doing Joins

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

Let's say I have this:

```
<entity name = "account">

...
...

<link-entity name="opportunity" from ="accountid" to ="accountid" link-type="outer">
```

How do I know if this is a `left outer join`, a `right outer join`, or a `full outer join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `left outer join`. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-left-outer-join-fetchxml-query-records-not-in)

And `right outer join` is not supported. [Reference](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/blog/2013/06/18/Limitations-with-CRM-FetchXML)

Same applies to `full outer join`. [Community discussion](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/312166)

Comment: what if link-entity is used but the link-type is not specified?